# ValueError: x, y, and format string must not be None (matplotlib.pyplot)

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, pyautogui

I am working on a random project in python with pyautgui,tkinter,matplotlib.pyplot. but when i run my code i get this error: `ValueError: x, y, and format string must not be None` I am running python 3.7.6 it also seems that this error is coming from either the `init` in my code or  `matplotlib.pyplot`

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tkinter import *
import pyautogui
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os

x = list(pyautogui.size())[0]
y = list(pyautogui.size())[1]
theme = '#4CAF50'


def init(input1,input2,input3):
    sum_list = []
    
    for (item1, item2) in zip(input1, input2):
        sum_list.append(item1 + item2)

def chart(init):
    plt.plot(init)
    plt.savefig('chart.png')
    plt.show()
    plt.close('all')
    return('chart.png')
   
def delete_file(file):
    if os.path.exists(file):
      os.remove(file)
    else:pass
    

X = init([31,3,1,2,3,4], [31,3,1,2,3,4], [31,3,1,2,3,4])
    
app = Tk()
app.state('zoomed')
app.title('')


Frame(app,bg=theme,width=x,height=70).place(x=0,y=0)
top_text = Label(text='Random project',bg=theme,fg='#FFFFFF')
top_text.place(x=x//2-100,y=10)
top_text.config(font=("Helvetica", 30))

#Graph
graph = chart(X)
file2 = Image.open(graph)
new_img = file2.resize((640,480),Image.ANTIALIAS)
graph_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(new_img)
graph_frame = Label(image=graph_img)
graph_frame.place(x=20,y=90) 


close_btn = Button(app,text='X',width=5,height=1,bg='red',fg='white',borderwidth=0,command=app.destroy)
close_btn.place(x=x-41,y=0)


app.bind("<F11>", lambda event: app.attributes("-fullscreen",not app.attributes("-fullscreen")))
app.bind("<Escape>", lambda event: app.attributes("-fullscreen", False))

app.mainloop()
delete_file('chart.png')
```

Comment: Your function `init` doesn't return anything. Therefore, `X = init(...)` makes `X` equal to None. Also, `init` has  3 parameters but only uses 2 of them.

Comment: @JohanC please turn your comment to an answer so i can verify it! :)